# How to allow laravel to accept special chars in url

Tags: laravel, url, routes

I have this working url on my local environment
http://dev1.conzumr.dev/img/PRINTER/HewlettPackardHP/585a750a4e2cf.thumb.png
it gives me png image but theres one more url
http://dev1.conzumr.dev/img/PRINTER/Hewlett+Packard+%28HP%29/5856ad8e7cafe.thumb.jpg

which also need to give me a image, but, giving not found http exception
because of the folder name **Hewlett+Packard+%28HP%29** in url
Please suggest me some solutions so i can grab the image on the url
**Using laravel 4.2**
Thanks in advance!

Comment: where my all comment gone rajender sir...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try where with your route like below example:

```
Route::get('add/{encoded_url}', function($encoded_url)
{
    return 'The URL is: '.rawurldecode($encoded_url);
})->where('encoded_url', '.*');
```

Just remember to run `composer dump-autoload` to reflect this change. Read more about [route param with laravel 4.2](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-parameters)

Comment: *fiend, BTW glad to help you..Cheer!!

Comment: Friend Thank you so much